# Add a UIViewController on top of all views, regardless of whether rootViewController changed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a framework and I'm trying to display a `UIViewController` over the top of all of the views, in a certain circumstance, regardless of whether the rootViewController of the `UIWindow` changes.

I initially tried presenting on top of the rootViewController of the keyWindow, but when that rootViewController changes the presentation of my view controller also disappears. I then tried adding my own `UIWindow` and setting the root view controller to my view controller, but that has the same issue if someone accesses and changes the keyWindow's root view controller.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Don't make your window the keyWindow?

Comment: Okay but if I don't do that it won't put it above all the other windows would it?

Comment: @Tometoyou - it is very difficult to answer abstract questions. Try to provide enough detail so we know exactly what you want to do... what you've tried to do... and what else is going on that is causing your approach not to work. For example, you say *"... when that rootViewController changes the presentation of my view controller also disappears"* -- What is your app / program flow doing that is changing the root view controller while you have "another view controller" on top of it?

Comment: @DonMag I believe I've provided enough detail thanks. I'm telling you the `rootViewController` changes, you don't need to know why

Comment: The "key" window receives keyboard (and other non-touch related) events (hence the name).  The z-order of windows is the windowLevel property, and you need to set isHidden to false

Comment: Your UIWindow is UIView, so you can add a subView on it.
It will be on top of anything. You don't need to bind your logic with UIViewController.